# org-default face not having effect

Tags: org-mode, faces

I want to set a different font for `org-mode` contents. Strangely, setting

`'(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit variable-pitch))))`

has the effect on headers as intended. However, setting

`'(org-default ((t (:inherit variable-pitch))))`

does not impact the text on normal `org-mode` text. They're still fixed-width font.

If I run `describe-face` on those text, it just says `default` instead of `org-default`. Not sure if that's the normal behavior.

How can I manually set font for normal `org-mode` content text?

Comment: It looks like the answer is on the mailing list -- i.e., `buffer-face-mode` needs to be enabled for buffer-local face settings such as changing the `'default`:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/84250

Comment: @lawlist That worked. Unfortunately it seems to turn *everything* within org-mode into variable-pitch... not only the normal texts.

Comment: @lawlist the OP is correct, `buffer-face-mode` changes *all* faces

Comment: Why not use `variable-pitch-mode` for this?  `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (variable-pitch-mode t)))`

Comment: @RichardBorder Actually I even forgot I asked this question. I already found a solution to what I need by using a combination of `variable-pitch-mode and customized face settings. You can see the related questions at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16819449/1460448 and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/org-block-background-font-not-having-effect/14886

Comment: @RichardBorder Well maybe this question still has its value on its own. But my point is that my original problem could be solved in a different way already, so I'm no longer really concerned with this specific question about `org-default` face.

Comment: @Timm Yeah I indeed solved my original problem with `variable-pitch-mode`. I guess this specific question about `org-default` face can still have some value on its own though.

Comment: @Mallory-Erik Thank you very much for the headsup! I need to renew the SSL certificate from letsencrypt from time to time. Apparently the renewal process hit some snags... I'll deal with that as soon as possible.