# org-block-background font not having effect

Tags: org-mode, faces

I use `variable-pitch-mode` with `org` buffers. Normally I set `org-block` to `fixed-pitch` and the code between `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` are properly rendered as fixed width fonts, also with proper syntax highlighting. However starting from last week, for some reason, although the code block font still had proper syntax highlighting, the face became the same as the `variable-pitch-face` as normal org-mode texts. I update my packages periodically and I think an update in `org-mode` caused the issue but I'm not sure what happened.

---

Update:

Turns out this is actually related to `org-block-background` face, which has been removed in org version 8.3.1 in commit `f8b42e8`, thus the bug. Not sure if there's a solution yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290924/fontify-r-code-blocks-in-org-mode-8 https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00510.html

I'm currently just locking my org-mode version to the older one.

---

Update 2:

The newest org-mode release, version 9.0.0, apparently lets `src-blocks` inherit `org-block` face, while the `org-block-background` face becomes obsolete. So now just by setting `org-block` face you should be able to have fixed-width fonts for all codes.

Comment: Fixed in [81af689d0f214c98c9bd45f482f18329c5e84ca1](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=81af689d0f214c98c9bd45f482f18329c5e84ca1).

Comment: @rasmus Thanks for the patch. However, this seems to work in an `#BEGIN_EXAMPLE` block, but doesn't work in `#BEGIN_SRC language_name`? Once the language should have its own syntax highlighting, the font reverts to variable-pitch in my case.

Comment: You need to use the master version -- what will eventually be Org-9.

Comment: @rasmus Just to confirm, in this version the face between `#BEGIN_SRC lang_name` and `#END_SRC` should be something other than `default`, right? Currently when I run `describe-face` inside of the block, I get `default`, which is the same font as normal text of orgmode. While between `#BEGIN_EXAMPLE` and `#END_EXAMPLE` it's `org-block` and for `~text~` it's `org-code`, for `=text=` it's `org-verbatim`, and thus those texts are displayed as fixed-pitch correctly.

Comment: @rasmus Since it's still `default` face beween `#BEGIN_SRC lang_name` and `#END_SRC`, it seems impossible to set it to fixed-pitch while keeping the normal content variable-pitch. I'm not sure I've correctly installed the master branch though.

Comment: No, I have fixed-pitch in code blocks and variable pitch elsewhere.  Note that I need to make more changes to the interface of this, IOW it's WIP.

Comment: @rasmus Now that Org 9 is out, I see this seems to be working. Thanks for the patch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this is actually related to org-block-background face, which has been removed in org version 8.3.1 in commit `f8b42e8`, thus the bug. The rationale seems to be

1. it causes a bug with `ps` export
2. it's inefficient

Maybe in the future there will be an alternative, but not yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290924/fontify-r-code-blocks-in-org-mode-8

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00510.html

Currently it seems the only way to get the old behavior back is to manually reverse the changes introduced in commit `f8b42e8`. You can see the commit here:

http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f8b42e8

```
diff --git a/lisp/org-faces.el b/lisp/org-faces.el
index e693dab..83453e8 100644
--- a/lisp/org-faces.el
+++ b/lisp/org-faces.el
@@ -537,9 +537,6 @@ follows a #+DATE:, #+AUTHOR: or #+EMAIL: keyword."
   :group 'org-faces
   :version "22.1")

-(defface org-block-background '((t ()))
-  "Face used for the source block background.")
-
 (org-copy-face 'org-meta-line 'org-block-begin-line
   "Face used for the line delimiting the begin of source blocks.")

diff --git a/lisp/org.el b/lisp/org.el
index a153151..7e30061 100644
--- a/lisp/org.el
+++ b/lisp/org.el
@@ -5930,15 +5930,7 @@ by a #."
          (cond
           ((and lang (not (string= lang "")) org-src-fontify-natively)
        (org-src-font-lock-fontify-block lang block-start block-end)
-       ;; remove old background overlays
-       (mapc (lambda (ov)
-           (if (eq (overlay-get ov 'face) 'org-block-background)
-               (delete-overlay ov)))
-             (overlays-at (/ (+ beg1 block-end) 2)))
-       ;; add a background overlay
-       (setq ovl (make-overlay beg1 block-end))
-                (overlay-put ovl 'face 'org-block-background)
-                (overlay-put ovl 'evaporate t)) ; make it go away when empty
+       (add-text-properties beg1 block-end '(src-block t)))
           (quoting
        (add-text-properties beg1 (min (point-max) (1+ end1))
                     '(face org-block))) ; end of source block
@@ -21828,9 +21820,7 @@ and end of string."
 When INSIDE is non-nil, don't consider we are within a src block
 when point is at #+BEGIN_SRC or #+END_SRC."
   (let ((case-fold-search t) ov)
-    (or (and (setq ov (overlays-at (point)))
-        (memq 'org-block-background
-          (overlay-properties (car ov))))
+    (or (and (eq (get-char-property (point) 'src-block) t))
    (and (not inside)
         (save-match-data
           (save-excursion
```

Comment: Thanks for digging that out -- that's a shame as I'd not really seen any of the problems myself.

Comment: @stuarthickinbottom Yeah I guess that change only occurred after my org-mode updated to 8.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when it changed, but I'm seeing it too.

Using `C-u C-x =` within such a block I can see it actually has the face `org-block-background` now, rather than `org-block`. Customising that face to inherit from `fixed-pitch` works for me.

Tested as follows:

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-block-background nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
```

If you want to preserve any existing inheritance on that face you could do the following (adapted from the original here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758139/variable-pitch-for-org-mode-fixed-pitch-for-tables/16819449#16819449):

```
(defun my-adjoin-to-list-or-symbol (element list-or-symbol)
    (let ((list (if (not (listp list-or-symbol))
                    (list list-or-symbol)
                  list-or-symbol)))
      (require 'cl-lib)
      (cl-adjoin element list)))

(set-face-attribute 'org-block-background nil :inherit
            (my-adjoin-to-list-or-symbol
             'fixed-pitch
             (face-attribute 'org-block-background :inherit)))
```

Comment: I've been using this method before this issue occurred. Turns out `org-block-background` face has been removed in org version 8.3.1, thus the bug probably. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290924/fontify-r-code-blocks-in-org-mode-8 https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00523.html

Comment: +1 for C-u C-x = I never knew that existed, and have been looking for something like this for a while now.